# Somar dias em data de input date

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um `input` do tipo date, gostaria de somar a ele 7 dias e colocar esse valor em outro `input` também do tipo date, tentei fazer assim:

```
<script>
$('#txtSolicitacao').on('blur', function(){
    data = $('#txtSolicitacao').val() + 7 ; 
    $('#txtTermino').val(data);
});
</script>
```

Obs: a data está no formato americano ano-mes-dia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suponho que é isto que voce procura.

```js
    $('#txtSolicitacao')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();

    $('#txtSolicitacao').change(function() {
      var date = this.valueAsDate;
      date.setDate(date.getDate() + 7);
      $('#txtTermino')[0].valueAsDate = date;
    });

    $('#txtSolicitacao').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="date" id="txtSolicitacao">
<br>
<input type="date" id="txtTermino">
```

Answer (score 1):

levando em consideração que o input[type='date'] armazena a data no formato ISO, você pode fazer o seguinte:

infelizmente o codigo abaixo só vai ficar amigavel nos navegadores baseados no Chromium, mas a logica para adicionar 7 dias permanece a mesma.

```js
var dataInicio = document.getElementById("dataInicio");
var dataFinal = document.getElementById("dataFinal");

dataInicio.addEventListener("focusout", function (event) {
  var offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
  var data = new Date(dataInicio.value);
  data.setMinutes(data.getMinutes() + offset);
  data.setDate(data.getDate() + 7);

  dataFinal.value = data.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
})

var event = new Event("focusout");
dataInicio.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<div>
  <label>
    Data Inicio: 
    <input id="dataInicio" type="date" value="2016-02-26" />
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    Data Final: 
    <input id="dataFinal" type="date" />
  </label>
</div>
```